# Does a burnt DVD/CD have the date and time it was burnt?

Tags: dvd-burning

I am just wondering if a CD or DVD burnt with UDF using ImgBurn (whether directly or by an ISO image generated by ImgBurn) will retain the date and time it was burnt, or that of the ISO image?

One time, I checked the properties of a burnt DVD in Win7, and there was no indication of any date or time anywhere, so perhaps it doesn't retain that information?

Comment: I don't see how we can answer this as the answer now may be different tomorrow... You should ask them direct.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the above question because, at the time, I didn't know that I could set the creation date and time of any ISO image or files that I burnt onto disc. As a result, I can now set whatever date and time I like, so that's my issue solved.